# combine two php script into single one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good morning, Everybody...

I want to combine two php code into single one, in order to reduce php multiple queries.

My first PHP script is like this:

```
<?php

include('wp-config.php');

$q = "SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $data[0];

?>
```

output of the above code is like below:

```
a1a2a3 x a x a4a5a6
```

My second PHP script is the same as the first one, except that it queries from `table2` instead:

```
<?php

include('wp-config.php');

                                     // this is different vvvvvv //
$q = "SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) FROM table2 ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $data[0];

?>
```

and the output is similar:

```
a1a2a3 x a x a4a5a6
```

now i want to combine above two similar php script into single one, i don't know how and the result should display like below...

```
Name1 (any text)
a1a2a3 x a x a4a5a6
Name2 (any text)
a1a2a3 x a x a4a5a6
```

can anybody help me in order to combine above two script 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for "UNION ALL" :

```
$q = "SELECT
          CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6)
      FROM
          table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
          CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6)
      FROM
          table2
      ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

That will combine the results of both queries into one result set

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by then use as following:

```
SELECT yourColumn FROM (        
SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) yourColumn FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) yourColumn FROM table2) newSet 
ORDER BY yourColumn
```

Without order:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) yourColumn FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) yourColumn FROM table2
```

Or you can order by, select id column also

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) yourColumn FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, CONCAT(a1,a2,a3,' x ',a,' x ',a4,a5,a6) yourColumn FROM table2    
ORDER BY id
```